# Tagit is not working

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I want to use "tagit", but it isn't working. Here is (part of) my code:

```
<ul style="float:right" name="company" id="company"> </ul> 

<script>

$("#company").tagit("add", {label: 'tag', value: 12});

</script>
```

Can you wise men, tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: there are no errors, my friend

Comment: What isn't working? What are you seeing? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

since no error is happening there is no issue in the plugin loading. Can you try this.Also which plugin are you using?

```
<script>    
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#company").tagit("add", {label: 'tag', value: 12});
})
</script>
```

Comment: <br/>
unfortunately it is still the same, my friend..    

  
I'm using:  <br/>
   jquery-1.8.2.js  <br/>
   jquery-ui.js  <br/>
   tagit-themeroller.js  <br/>

also, should I change "ul" to "input" ? (it doesn't work either)

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle so that we can have a close look at the code.

Comment: I did it, my friend, I did it ^_^

Comment: congrats dude... what was the issue??

Comment: @Nodarius My friend. What was the issue ?

Comment: I wish I remembered it, brother